# Articles Drag-n-Drop Ordering Not Working

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, administrator, article-manager

I have noticed a strange problem since upgrading to Joomla 3.3.6.

In the Article Manager, the Ordering column no longer works - no arrows, no numbers, no drag-n-drop icons.  This is also the same for Featured Articles.  However, Categories works fine.

I have searched online but can't find anyone with the same problem, so I think it may be one of the plugins I have installed (could that cause such a problem?).

I just wondered if anyone else has experienced the same thing or if anyone has any other suggestions...

[image: Article Manager Screen]

Comment: Press `F12` to open the browser console, click on the `Console` tab, refresh the page and see if there are any errors. It works fine for me so I'm thinking you might have a custom script causing issues

Comment: Is Joomla and all your extensions up to date (latest version)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the problem, you make sure you have clicked the column title for sorting. Also, you can try to filter articles by category first, because I dont think you can sort articles from different categories.

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but I don't think it's the problem  - I tried your idea on my end, and then noticed in her screenshot that it IS sorted as you suggested, so the reordering should be showing.  Also, you can reorder without filtering, though you are limited to where you can drag for re-ordering.